# Is there a better way to handle the Doctrine proxy object

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have two classes linked with a one-to-one relation.

```
class Client {
    ...
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="ClientInfo")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="client_id")
     */
    private $info;
    ...
    public function doSomething() {
        if (!$this->getInfo() instanceof ClientInfo) {
            return false;
        }
        return $this->getInfo()->doSomething();
    }
    ...
}

class ClientInfo {
    ...
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Client")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="client_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $client;
    ...
    public function doSomething() {
        return 'something';
    }
    ...
}
```

Those classes are loaded with database content with Doctrine. It is working perfectly when there is data in the database. But if there is not ClientInfo data, I have a *\Doctrine\ORM\EntityNotFoundException* raised.

So I changed the *doSomething()* method to take this into account.

```
    public function doSomething() {
        if (!$this->getInfo() instanceof ClientInfo) {
            return false;
        }
        try {
            return $this->getInfo()->doSomething();
        } catch (\Doctrine\ORM\EntityNotFoundException $e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

But it does not feel right to me since it is tied with *Doctrine*. I am trying to modify my unit tests to add a mock of the proxy object but it does not feel right either.

Is there a better way of doing that?

**EDIT 1**

I followed Nico Kaag suggestion but it does not change anything.

My constructor in my Client class look like this:

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->info = new ClientInfo();
}
```

If I do a var_dump of *$this->info* after retrieving my object with Doctrine, this is what I get.

```
object(Proxies\__CG__\MyBundle\Entity\ClientInfo)[444]
  public '__initializer__' => 
    object(Closure)[461]
  public '__cloner__' => 
    object(Closure)[462]
  public '__isInitialized__' => boolean false
  private 'client' (MyBundle\Entity\ClientInfo) => string '21055' (length=5)
  ...
```

**EDIT 2**

I finally changed what I have done. I removed the try..catch block and change the query to retrieve objects from database. Now I force the query to retrieve the *ClientInfo* object at the same time as the *Client* object.

This way, I can trust my test and if I forget to query both objects simultaneously, I will have an exception to remind it to me.

Comment: You can set the $info object in the constructor of the Client class, Doctrine will override it when there is an actual object. So in your constructor you would say: $this->info = new ClientInfo();

The side-effect of this, is that every time you create a Client and store a client, the client info will also be stored. You can use the cascade options to change this to the way you want.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it does not work. I still need to catch _\Doctrine\ORM\EntityNotFoundException_.

Comment: If I set up the _$info_ in the constructor, my unit tests are still working fine.

Comment: What is your output when you do a var dump of $this->info ?

Comment: I edited the post to add your suggestions

Comment: I would be careful about asking questions like this. It can be flagged as **off-topic**, because you are asking for a debugging-like solution which is kind of not okay.

Answer (score 2):

See I have made classes for you.

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping AS ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class client
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Entities\client_info", inversedBy="client")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="client_info_id", referencedColumnName="id", unique=true)
     */
    private $clientInfo;
}
```

---

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping AS ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class client_info
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Entities\client", mappedBy="clientInfo")
     */
    private $client;
}
```

Try this, you will not get such issue.

Also I have used **bi-directional** relation with cardinality one-to-one, parent connection 0:1*- (parent optional), please see the diagram.

[image: ER diagram]

Suggetion : Use ORM designer tool for designing and extracting entity classes.